# Getting NPE when using getServletConfig().getServletContext().getAttribute() (Java)

Tags: java, servlets

I am using Servlets from not a long time. And i am getting this problem, which i can't terminate myself. I am using Servlets to create a small web project, and i tried to add my Service and DAO objects to ServletContext.

```
HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class com.taxi.service.controller.LoginController

type Exception report

message Error instantiating servlet class com.taxi.service.controller.LoginController

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class com.taxi.service.controller.LoginController
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.getServletContext(GenericServlet.java:123)
    com.taxi.service.controller.LoginController.<init>(LoginController.java:16)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:379)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <display-name>Jean taxi-service</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.taxi.service.utils.ApplicationContext</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>InitController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.taxi.service.controller.InitController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>LoginController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.taxi.service.controller.LoginController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>RegistrationController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.taxi.service.controller.RegistrationController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>PrivateAreaController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.taxi.service.controller.PrivateAreaController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>OrderController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.taxi.service.controller.OrderController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ReviewController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.taxi.service.controller.OrderController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>AdminController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.taxi.service.controller.AdminController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>InitController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LoginController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RegistrationController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/registration</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>OrderController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/orderCreation</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ReviewController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/review</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>PrivateAreaController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/privateArea</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AdminController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/adminPanel</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- <error-page>
        <location>/WEB-INF/pages/error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    -->

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>45</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <resource-ref>
        <description>DB Connection</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/order_board</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    </login-config>

</web-app>
```

ServletContext listener class:

```
public class ApplicationContext implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        servletContextEvent.getServletContext().setAttribute("clientDao", new ClientDaoImpl(DataBaseUtil.getConnectionPoolInstance()));
        servletContextEvent.getServletContext().setAttribute("orderDao", new ClientDaoImpl(DataBaseUtil.getConnectionPoolInstance()));
        servletContextEvent.getServletContext().setAttribute("clientService", new ClientServiceImpl());
        servletContextEvent.getServletContext().setAttribute("orderService", new OrderServiceImpl());
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {

    }
}
```

Login controller class:

```
public class LoginController extends HttpServlet {

    private ClientService clientService = (ClientServiceImpl) getServletConfig().getServletContext().getAttribute("clientService");

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
       ...
    }

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response{
        /**
         *...something doing with clientService
         */
    }
}
```

When i am trying to get my Service object from ServletContext, which a were added, in these line i am getting NPE:

```
private ClientService clientService = (ClientServiceImpl) getServletConfig().getServletContext().getAttribute("clientService");
```

What should i do, to make this npe exception gone and my clientService work.
Thanks a lot. 
p.s. I will read all the proposes and asnwers, and hope you can help me in this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize your field in an overriden `init(ServletConfig)` method. The `ServletConfig` is not available at instance initialization time.

```
@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);
    this.clientService = config.getServletContext().getAttribute("clientService");
}
```

From the [javadoc of `Servlet#init(ServletConfig)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html#init-javax.servlet.ServletConfig-)

> Called by the servlet container to indicate to a servlet that the
>   servlet is being placed into service.
>
> The servlet container calls the `init` method exactly once after
>   instantiating the servlet. The `init` method must complete successfully
>   before the servlet can receive any requests.

The [javadoc of the `GenericServlet` implementation of `init(ServletConfig)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#init-javax.servlet.ServletConfig-) further specifies

> This implementation stores the `ServletConfig` object it receives from
>   the servlet container for later use. When overriding this form of the
>   method, call `super.init(config)`.

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot! It helped me! 
May i ask you something more?

If i had many Service objects, i must to Override init method in every controller where i must to use this objects, or i can make this initialization in one place?
Thank you.

Comment: @davakin111 You can create an `HttpServlet` superclass which all your servlets extend. If you don't want all your servlets to have access to all services, you'll need to retrieve the services individually. Whether you do it in an `init` method or inside the `doXyz` handlers is up to you.

Comment: Thank you :) 
It was the best answer.